# Arduino button and led

Tags: arduino-uno

Program below is my program for my button and LED, but it's not functioning the way I want it too. The LED is supposed to light up before I press switch 9, but it is lighting up immediately.

```
const int sw9=9;
const int sw10=10;
const int sw11=11;
const int sw12=12;
const int sw13=13;
int timer=250;
int s=0;
void setup()
{
  for (int opin=1;opin<=8;opin++)
{
  pinMode(opin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sw9,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(sw10,INPUT);
  pinMode(sw11,INPUT);
  pinMode(sw12,INPUT);
  pinMode(sw13,INPUT);
}
}
void loop(){
{ 
while (s==0)

for (int opin=1;opin<=8;opin++)
{
digitalWrite(opin,HIGH);
delay(timer);
digitalWrite(opin,LOW);
if(digitalRead(sw9)==LOW);
}

{
s=1;
delay(timer);
}
}
while(s==1)
for (int opin=1;opin<=8;opin++)
{
digitalWrite(opin,LOW);
if(digitalRead(sw9)==HIGH);
}
}
```

Comment: "LED is supposed to light up before i press switch 9 but it is lighting up immediately. " so before. I recommend to take a coding course

Comment: The only way you can more or less implement that requirement, is to use an ultrasonic distance sensor (e.g. HC-SR04), and measure the distance from the button to something coming towards it ... which hopefully presses the button and does not move away before pressed.

Comment: You will wind up in trouble later on if you don't do some kind of formatting. It becomes very difficult to read or edit code if everything starts from far left with no tabs or spaces. You can select everything and hit Control+T to autoformat your code. I agree with @Juraj, benefit yourself and take a basic coding class. YouTube is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(digitalRead(sw9)==LOW);

if(digitalRead(sw9)==HIGH);
```

Both of these have the effect of "read the switch and then do nothing"

Change them to

```
if(digitalRead(sw9)==HIGH){
// do intended action
}
```